# How to store a boolean value using SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, boolean, sharedpreferences

Please write the work code
HOW TO, using sharedpreference, save boolean flag state (true, false)
AFTER CLOSING APPLICATION *

```
boolean flag = true;
......
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (flag)
                {
                    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_alarm_on1);
                alarm();}
                else {
                    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_alarm_on);
                alarmoff();}
                flag = !flag;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write to SharedPreferences in Fragment like this.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("my-key", true);
editor.apply();
```

And then u can retrieve it like this:

```
boolean myBoolean = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("my-key", /*Default*/ true);
```

Then you need to decide where you want to execute this.
If it only should be when app gets closed, i would do it in onStop() or onDestroy(). A closer look to the fragment lifecycle will help. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, but could you show me how it will look in my code above?